# Find CPU CORE using WMI query

Tags: wmi-query

I want to list out the CPU Core / Processes in the system. When I have used ***select DeviceID from Win32_Processor***, I got **CPU0** as result; But I am expecting result as "**CPU0,CPU1,CPU2,CPU3**" since there are multiple cores. Is there any other one liner available for finding out this?

Thanking you...

Comment: You can get number of cores but not listed in that fashion that you are asking for.

Comment: I have seen it like this in a monitoring tool.

Comment: Just assuming, tool might have done this: you get number of cores i.e. 4 then you can list them as CPU0, CPU1, CPU2, CPU3 from your code... :)

Comment: May be right.... anyway thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old , but for others searching , Win32_Processor it contains, NumberOfCores  and NumberOfLogicalProcessors